# Node.js: Is the NPM documentation up to date?

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm looking through the documentation for NPM (Node Package Manager) and I'm unable to find information on all of the commands. These are the commands that come with NPM:

```
add-user, adduser, apihelp, author, bin, bugs, c, cache,
    completion, config, ddp, dedupe, deprecate, docs, edit,
    explore, faq, find, find-dupes, get, help, help-search,
    home, i, info, init, install, isntall, la, link, list, ll,
    ln, login, ls, outdated, owner, pack, prefix, prune,
    publish, r, rb, rebuild, remove, restart, rm, root,
    run-script, s, se, search, set, show, shrinkwrap, star,
    start, stop, submodule, tag, test, tst, un, uninstall,
    unlink, unpublish, unstar, up, update, version, view,
    whoami
```

Yet a nice handful of these commands are not included in the documentation. Is the documentation up to date or what? Is there perhaps better, more clear and thorough documentation of the NPM? I haven't seen anything on GitHub.

Comment: What specifically is missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is up to date, and there isn't anything actually missing from it. It's just that many of the commands are undocumented aliases of other commands. To find the real command behind an alias, just type `npm help <alias>`.

Here's a list of aliases as of the posting of this answer:

```
add-user     adduser
apihelp      help
author       owner
c            config
find         search
find-dupes   dedupe
get          config
home         docs
i            install
info         view
isntall      install
la           ls
list         ls
ll           ls
ln           link
login        adduser
r            rm
rb           rebuild
remove       rm
s            search
se           search
set          config
show         view
tst          test
un           rm
uninstall    rm
unlink       rm
up           update
```

Comment: Thanks! That was clear. Covered exactly the commands I was wondering about.